# Are tweets or Instagram posts copyrighted?

Tags: copyright, internet, intellectual-property

There are accounts on Twitter and Instagram that make money by posting sponsored content. Let's say another account does the same thing, but it just copies the tweets/posts from the more popular accounts. Would the more popular account have a case if it were to sue the account copying its content? The smaller account being run from America.

Answer (score 4):

Copyright subsists in "original works of authorship fixed in any tangible medium of expression..." [17 USC §102](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/102)

Originality requires "independent creation plus a modicum of creativity". [Feist Pubs., Inc. v. Rural Tel. Svc. Co., Inc.](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/499/340/case.html) 499 U.S. 340 (1991)

The creator of a work generally owns the copyright to that work. [17 USC §201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/201)

[Twitter's Terms of Service](https://twitter.com/tos?lang=en#yourrights) say:

> **You retain your rights to any Content you submit**, post or display on or through the Services. By submitting, posting or displaying Content on or through the Services, **you grant us a worldwide, non-exclusive, royalty-free license (with the right to sublicense) to use, copy, reproduce, process, adapt, modify, publish, transmit, display and distribute such Content** in any and all media or distribution methods (now known or later developed).

So, you maintain the copyright ownership, and you grant Twitter a licence to do whatever Twitter wants with that work. This allows Twitter to show your tweet around its network and to allow for re-tweeting etc. (Although, it could have done those things with a less permissive licence.) You are not giving other users that licence.

Comment: "You are not giving other users that licence." - but Twitter could - "with the right to sublicense"